# Postfix setting to enable emails to usernames

Tags: postfix

I am trying to get postfix set up to send mail to a user with out specifying the domain. I believe the issue is that the email domain and the server domain are different.

The company email addresses are username@company.com and the server is built with  the domain cmpny.com.

I have tried adding company.com to the mydestinations but line in the main.cf but it is not helping.

Any advice would be great!

Thanks,
Joe

Comment: If you put recipient domain in mydestination then Postfix will try to deliver mail locally, is this what you expect?

Comment: Locally, as in to the mail system on the local machine? or locally as in the domain in the mydestination?

Answer (score 0):

If you put company.com in `mydestination`, then you're telling postfix that he's the hosting mailserver for company.com. If that's what you want then do the following:

1. Create an user: `useradd -m -s /bin/bash testuser`
2. Then do (you may need mailutils package): `echo "Hi there" | mail -s Testing testuser`
3. Then switch to user: `su testuser`
4. And check for mail: `mail`

You should have your mail listed.

The same will work if you put testuser@company.com at #2

Comment: Sorry if it is unclear. What I want is for postfix to send the email to An existing email address (testuser@company.com) with the command you used in step 2.

What section on the postfix/main.cf would i need to enable that to happen?

Comment: that address exists on your postfix server, or in the internet?

Comment: As far as i am aware there is no main postfix server. Most of the other servers in our environment use sendmail.